# In a PHP extension, recommended way to return the value from and std::string

Tags: php, c++, memory-management, php-extension

We have a simple PHP function, whose purpose is to call a C++ free function `std::string callLibrary(std::string)` and to return its `std::string` return value.

It currently looks like that:

```
PHP_FUNCTION(call_library)
{
    char *arg = NULL;
    size_t arg_len, len;
    if (zend_parse_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS(), "s", &arg, &arg_len) == FAILURE)
    {
        return;
    }

    // Call underlying library
    std::string callResult = callLibrary(arg);
    zend_string * result = zend_string_init(callResult.c_str(), callResult.size(), 0);
    RETURN_STR(result);
}
```

We cannot find a reference manual describing the behaviours of `zend_string_init`or `RETURN_STR()`, the closest thing we have being:
http://www.phpinternalsbook.com/php7/internal_types/strings/zend_strings.html

In particular, it states for the last parameter of `zend_string_init`

> If you pass 0, you ask the engine to use a request-bound heap
>   allocation using the Zend Memory Manager. Such allocation will be
>   destroyed at the end of the current request. If you don’t do it
>   yourself, on a debug build, the engine will shout at you about a
>   memory leak you just created. If you pass 1, you ask for what we
>   called a “persistent” allocation, that is the engine will use a
>   traditional C malloc() call and will not track the memory allocation
>   in any way.

It seems we want the `0` value, but does `RETURN_STR()` then free the allocated memory? (the text is a bit ambiguous, but it seems the destruction should be explicit)
Is there a more idiomatic way to return such `std::string` value from a PHP extension function?

Comment: "Such allocation will be destroyed at the end of the current request" this might mean that it's just tracked memory that is destroyed when the PHP executable exits (relying on the OS to free it up)

Comment: @apokryfos Indeed, this first sentence seems to imply that there is some automatic disposal in place. Yet, the following sentence is "If you don’t do it yourself, on a debug build, the engine will shout at you about a memory leak you just created", which would imply that the destruction has to requested explicitly. (This is why the question states that the description is ambiguous :)

Comment: It's generally accepted that not deallocating memory you've allocated in a language that doesn't have garbage collection built-in is considered a memory leak. Not sure why but it may have to do with how these languages are very often used to write software that is meant to be running 24/7 and therefore any memory you don't deallocate is going to pile on. In your case it shouldn't be a problem but it is probably still bad practice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question, I'll talk a little about PHP memory allocation, then about your specific question.

**About PHP Memory Allocation**

When writing PHP extensions, there are two kinds of memory allocations you can perform:

- tracked memory allocations
- persistent memory allocations

A tracked memory allocation is an optimization that allows the PHP engine to have some more control over raw memory allocation. The Zend memory manager (ZendMM) acts as a wrapper above the standard memory allocation libraries. This memory manager allows PHP to avoid memory leaks by cleaning up any tracked memory that has not been explicitly freed at the end of a request. Furthermore this allows the engine to enact memory limits (such as the `php.ini` setting [`memory_limit`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit)). Tracked memory is also referred to as *per-request* memory for these reasons.

A persistent memory allocation is the standard memory allocation managed by the C library (e.g `malloc` and friends). It's worth noting also that in C++, `new` and `delete` typically call down to `malloc` and `free` respectively. In PHP, a persistent memory allocation survives the handling of a request, and it may exist to service more than one request. For this reason, it is possible to  cause a memory leak with these kinds of allocations.

In the PHP API, there are some macros that are defined for performing tracked or persistent memory allocations. For example, `emalloc` and `efree` are the analogs to `malloc` and `free` for tracked (i.e. per-request) memory management. The macros `pemalloc` and `pefree` are for either tracked or persistent allocations, having a parameter to toggle. For example, `pemalloc(32,1)` allocates a block of 32 persistent bytes whereas `pemalloc(32,0)` is equivalent to `emalloc(32)` which allocates a block of 32 tracked bytes.

In addition to the raw memory allocation functions, the PHP API also provides control over memory allocations initiated by higher-level functions. For example, creating a PHP7 `zend_string` structure with `zend_string_init` lets you choose what kind of memory allocation you want via the third parameter. This follows a common idiom throughout the API, with `0` indicating a tracked allocation and `1` indicating a persistent allocation.

**Regarding `zend_string`, `zend_string_init` and `RETURN_STR`**

I'm not as familiar with PHP7 as I am with PHP5, but many concepts have carried over and I think I've read enough of the source code to answer the question. When you assign a `zend_string` to a `zval` using `RETURN_STR`, the `zval` becomes responsible for freeing the `zend_string` (in PHP5 this was just a `char*` but the concept is the same). The Zend engine expects most if not all objects to be allocated using the tracked memory manager. In PHP5, a string assigned to a `zval` must have been allocated via `emalloc` since the code always calls `efree` on the string buffer when the `zval` is destroyed. In PHP7 there seems to be [an exception](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/5eb1f92f31cafc48384f9096012f421b37f6d425/Zend/zend_string.h#L263) since the `zend_string` structure can remember which allocation type was used. Regardless, it's a good practice to always use the tracked allocations as a default unless you have a good reason to do otherwise. Therefore your current code looks good since it passes `0` as the third parameter to `zend_string_init`.

The destruction of the `zend_string` should not be explicit in your code since the `zval` will handle that at some later time. Plus, that process is dependent on how userspace operates on the returned `zval`. This is not something you have to worry about.