# How to check if return_value (from php function, inside native extension) is used in php userland?

Tags: php, php-extension

So i'm writing an extension to act as a wrapper for a certain multithreaded networking library. Now, the pattern used is a simple request-reply.

All I want to do is allocate a zend_string (with zend_string_init) for the reply, and return it via return_value. The thing is, I don't want to explicitly call zend_string_release, because of how php treats zvals.

What I mean by that is: if a certain zval gets to php userland, it will be destroyed and freed after it is no longer used. If it doesn't get there (e.g. a user will use in php something like "myfunc();", instead of "$result = myfunc();" ), I have to destroy it.

I find this to be quite a tricky case. I wonder if there isn't some function or macro or field in the execute_data parameter, that can tell me if the result from my function is used in php or not. If it isn't used,  then it means that I don't need to alloc memory for the reply. If it is, I will alloc memory and return it, and it will be freed automatically.

EDIT: if such a mechanism doesn't exist or isn't reliable or isn't best practice to use (as another user pointed out), how should memory be managed?

For instance something like

```
PHP_FUNCTION(myfunc)
{
  zend_string *dummy = zend_string_init("dummy", sizeof("dummy") - 1, 0);
  RETVAL_STR(dummy);
  return;
}
```

would cause a memory leak if the user doesn't do something like $var = myfunc() in php, and it would also cause a double free if the user does indeed do
$var = myfunc() and I do something like zend_string_release(dummy) in the RSHUTDOWN() function (assuming i have a pointer to it saved somehow in a global hashtable)

Comment: Generally speaking a function should not change its behaviour depending on how it is being called. If anything, an additional parameter to signal whether it should return anything or not would make sense. I'd rephrase the question to ask for a specific solution regarding allocation of memory in this case, not about detecting the use of the return value.

Comment: I understand your point. However, I'm not sure if adding an extra parameter does any good. What I want to guard against are memory leaks or double frees. If a user specifies via this extra parameter that he wants the function to return something, and yet he does not do anything with the result, then I have a memory leak on my hands. All that considered, I agree that I should perhaps rephrase the question a bit.

Comment: So, yes, ask your question about this specific conundrum and how it should typically be dealt with in a PHP extension. Again, detecting whether the return value is used in userland code is probably the wrong way to go about that.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you shouldn't have to worry about handling the lifecycle of a function's return value. The PHP engine handles this value just like any other value in userland. In other words, your conception of the return value "being used" (or "not being used") in userland is not quite correct. In fact, *every* return value is "used" by the engine whether the userland code assigns the return value to a variable or not. This means PHP's automatic memory management is applied and everything is handled and eventually freed properly.

Underneath the hood, every `PHP_FUNCTION` is passed a `zval` having the argument name `return_value` (of course, the `PHP_FUNCTION` macro hides this fact). This `zval` is always initialized to `NULL` (e.g. `ZVAL_NULL(return_value)`) before the function is even called. The macro `RETVAL_STR(str)` evaluates into the call `ZVAL_STR(return_value,str)`, which assigns the `zend_string*` to the existing `return_value` `zval`. Keeping in mind that a `zend_string` is a reference-counted structure, the assigning `zval` *inherits* the initial reference set via `zend_string_init`. The engine will then handle reference-counting the assigned `zend_string*` and will eventually call `zend_string_release` once the `zend_string`'s reference counter hits zero (i.e. it is no longer in use by any `zval`s). The engine handles destroying the `return_value` `zval` after potentially assigning the value to another `zval` via a variable assignment, function call parameter assignment, ETC.

Note: if anyone reading this is more familiar with PHP5 than PHP7 (like myself), then note it is the same concept except the `zend_string*` is a `char*`, and in PHP5 the `zval` itself is reference-counted instead of the `zend_string`.

So, for example, consider this:

```
<?php
myfunc();
```

The return value is handled by the engine in this instance like we'd expect using PHP's reference-counting system. The refcount for the `zend_string*` peaks at `1` and is decremented once before being destroyed. In other words, the `zend_string` lives entirely within the `return_value` `zval` before getting cleaned up. Now consider this other case:

```
<?php
$val = myfunc();
echo "Got message: $val\n";
```

In this case, the return value is *still handled in the exact same way* using the reference-counting system, albeit for a longer amount of time (i.e. more refcount increments/decrements). The refcount will at least hit `2` when the return value is assigned to `$val`. When the engine destroys the `return_value` `zval`, the refcount will decrement to `1` since the `zend_string*` is still alive in `$val`.

I hope this cleared things up. Note that I also answered a [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50465101/in-a-php-extension-recommended-way-to-return-the-value-from-and-stdstring/50788224#50788224) to yours a while back; it may be useful to you as well.